# How to control access control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, role

- I have *asp.net* project which has got *GridViews, Buttons, Navigators* etc...
- I have *10-15 role types*. For example:

Access Management must be:

### Products.aspx

- `RoleType1` can see `GridView1`, `Gv2`,  `Gv3`(But can not see `Gv3's column2`)
- `RoleType2` can see `Gv1`,`Gv2` (But can not see `Gv2's column3`), `Gv3`( (But can not see `Gv3's Column4`)

Also:

- `RoleType3` can see `button1`, `button2` (But can not see `Button3`), Can see `Gv2`(But can not see `Gv2's column3`)

### ProductsDetail.aspx

- `RoleType1` can see `GridView1`,`Gv3`,  `Gv2`(But can not see `Gv2's column3`),`Gv4`
- `RoleType2` can see `Gv3`,`Gv4` (But can not see `Gv3's column3`), Gv4( (But can not see `Gv4's Column4`)

Also:

- `RoleType3` can see `button3`, `button4` (But can not see `Button1`), Can see `Gv2`(But can not see `Gv2's column5`)

I can create more fantastic scenario. how can I manage this role?
i want to separate this role types from *WEB.CONFIG*.

For example I can write *sql db* this role and than I create an *xml* and than write xml from db. Do you have any idea to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at [Microsoft-s AzMan-Authorization Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897401.aspx) ?

It contains an API to program against to ask  CanSeeGridView1, CanSeeGridView2, ...

and a gui (azman.msc) where you can define roles and map rights (RoleType1 can see GridView1) and store them in an xml-file.

Comment: Thank you but can you show me a little trick? Gridview'Columns buttons more gridview?

Comment: sorry i donot know much about asp.net grid.